# Le « racisme anti-francophone(s) » : qualification de la base, nombre ?

Tags: vocabulaire, pluriel, préfixes, sport, mots-composés

Le [capitaine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Comtois) de l'équipe canadienne de hockey junior avait « [raté un tir de pénalité obtenu en prolongation, alors que la marque était de 1-1](https://www.lapresse.ca/sports/hockey-junior/201901/03/01-5209829-une-vague-de-haine-virtuelle-deferle-sur-maxime-comtois.php) » et le Canada avait donc perdu le match et a donc « [été exclu de la ronde des médailles pour la première fois en 21 ans](https://www.lapresse.ca/sports/hockey-junior/201901/04/01-5209980-affaire-maxime-comtois-la-ministre-isabelle-charest-reagit.php) ». Certains propos déplorables ont été tenu à son endroit par la suite, dans un contexte de [cyberintimidation](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8350255), dont celui-ci :

> J'espère que tu attraperas le sida, maudit Français.
>
> [ Aboiement retranscrit sur un réseau social et rapporté ds. *La presse* ]

Maxime Comtois est un Québécois francophone. C'est non sans rappeler d'[autres évènements](https://www.lapresse.ca/sports/hockey/201901/08/01-5210280-subban-soutient-un-ado-victime-de-racisme.php), dans un contexte où la droite cautionne, soit par incurie soit à dessein, le dénigrement systématique de la dignité humaine. Le chef du Parti Québécois, Pascal Bérubé, a qualifié ces propos de *racisme [anti-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/anti-)francophone**s*** et un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/sports/hockey-junior/201901/09/01-5210497-victime-dintimidation-le-joueur-de-hockey-maxime-comtois-reagit.php) rapporte plutôt *racisme [anti-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/anti-)francophone* au singulier.

---

J'ai de la difficulté à [analyser](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1463) si la forme au pluriel est tributaire d'un accord avec un générique sous-jacent (*les propos*) ou du groupe *des francophones* ou si il est plus cohérent de voir la base [*francophone*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/francophone) au singulier, et je ne saurais dire si la base est un nom ou un adjectif, ou si l'on est davantage inspiré ici par une phrase complète employant les prépositions [*contre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/contre/0) ou [envers](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/envers/0). Je n'ai pas trouvé de [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=racisme%20anti-francophones%2Cracisme%20anti-francophone%2Cpr%C3%A9jug%C3%A9s%20envers%20les%20francophones%2Cpr%C3%A9jug%C3%A9s%20contre%20les%20francophones&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) utile.

- Peut-on qualifier les composants du mot composé (racisme)
  *anti-francophone(s)* et expliquer si l'on trouve le singulier ou le pluriel davantage cohérent ou clair et pourquoi ?
- Incidemment, peut-on expliquer si le terme [*racisme*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/racisme), tel
  qu'employé dans ce contexte, serait *envers* ou *contre* quelqu'un ?

Answer (score 1):

> Le chef du Parti Québécois, Pascal Bérubé, a qualifié ces propos de
>   racisme anti-francophones

Il semble évident que ce ne sont pas les *propos* qui sont qualifiés d'*anti-francophone*, donc le pluriel ne peut venir de là.
En revanche, ici, c'est le racisme qui est anti-francocophone, donc accord avec ce mot (donc singulier, de mon point de vue). Cette analyse va à l'encontre de certaines sources, donc je détaille mon raisonnement *infra*.

Dans les cas où est qualifiée une chose, il n'y a pas de difficulté ([exemple dans *le Monde* en 2005](https://www.lemonde.fr/a-la-une/article/2005/03/15/manifestations-de-lyceens-le-spectre-des-violences-anti-blancs_401648_3208.html), au pluriel, à propos du *racisme anti-Blanc*, dont l'évolution en *antiblanc* va dans le sens de mon analyse, d'ailleurs).

En revanche, quant à savoir s'il faut employer un singulier "générique" ou accorder en raison de la multiplicité des individus visés, cela reste plus discutable. Il faut d'abord distinguer s'il la deuxième partie du composé est un nom ou un adjectif. Voyons ce qu'en pense Jean Girodet (*Pièges et difficultés de la langue française*, 1988, art. « anti », III) :

> 1. Quand le second élément est un adjectif, il est variable : *Des décisions anticonstitutionnelles.*

Manifestement, nous ne sommes pas ici dans ce cas.

> 4. Quand le second élément est un **nom** désignant ce contre quoi on lutte (inconvénient, etc.), l'usage est flottant. Il est conseillé de
>      laisser le composé invariable quand il est adjectif et de mettre la
>      marque du pluriel quand il est employé comme nom : *des phares
>      antibrouillard, des antibrouillards.*

C'est plutôt de cela dont il s'agit. Mais Girodet ajoute une exception qui pourrait correspondre, puisqu'il est question d'*antijeune* :

> 5. Quand le second élément est un nom qui est déjà au pluriel dans le
>      composé au singulier, ce composé est évidemment invariable : *La loi
>      anticasseurs ( = contre les casseurs). Le racisme antijeunes (contre
>      les jeunes).* [...]

André Jouette précise :

> Les mots nouveaux commençant par « anti » ne sont quelquefois que de
>   pseudo-adjectifs : en formulant « mesures antifroid », on entend
>   toujours : *des mesures contre le froid.* (Jouette, *Dictionnaire
>   d'orthographe et d'expression écrite*, 1993, art. « anti »).

Sont-ce des mesures « contre le francophone » ? Cela semble peu naturel, donc le cas décrit par Jouette ne correspond pas. Ainsi, d'après l'exemple de Girodet, il faudrait parler de *racisme anti-francophones* (voire *antifrancophones*, mais c'est une autre histoire, et je trouve ça peu lisible, même si ça a son importance, je vais y revenir).

Maintenant, un coup d'œil à la page Wikipédia « Racisme antiblanc » nous apprend dès le titre que cette analyse n'est peut-être plus très suivie par l'usage. Une recherche sur *Antidote 9* concernant *antijeune* nous donne deux cooccurrences au singulier (deux articles de Marianne 2, donc des sources très récentes) et aucune au pluriel :

Et si cela témoignait justement d’un racisme antijeune particulièrement pervers?
Marianne2.fr

De façon plus personnelle, je pense qu'il en est du singulier comme de la perte du trait d'union dans la préfixation avec *anti*. Lorsque le mot est entré dans le langage courant, lexicalisé, il perd sa qualité de composé, devient un terme à part entière, perd du même coup son trait d'union et sa tendance à s'accorder selon le sens pour en venir à un accord traditionnel, plus syntaxique.

Donc : *du racisme anti-francophones* (= contre les francophones) puis *du racisme antifrancophone* (car c'est le racisme qui est antifrancophone : on ne fait plus appel aux termes de la composition). Le maintien du tiret est possible, mais là, on entre aussi dans un autre sujet, qui a à voir avec l'esthétique de la langue écrite et la qualité du langage inventé (Jouette évoque à juste titre la paresse d'un usage excessif de ce préfixe - *ibid*.).

Answer (score 0):

Ça dépend de si tu considères anti-francophone strictement comme un adjectif, et tu l'accordes donc avec le nom singulier, ou comme si tu le considères comme un qualificatif plus vague, et donc il devient anti-francophones parce qu'il s'applique évidemment a tous les francophones.  Tu cherches ici une certitude qui est autrement laissée à l'appréciation de l'écrivain.